# Redirect and show the component if user is logged in in React

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have a login page which is a public route and a dashboard page which is a private route as follows:

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <PublicRoute path="/" exact component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And this is my private route component:

```
let store = require("store");
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...options}) => {
    //   const finalComponent = user != null && user.auth == true ? component : Login;

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        setUserData(store.get("userData"));
    }, []);
    return (
        <Route
            {...options}
            render={(props) =>
                store.get("userData") ?
                    <Component {...props} />
                    :
                    <Redirect to="/"/>
            }
        />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Now the problem that I am facing is that if I open the dashboard `localhost:9999/dashboard` none of my components are visible because they are routed inside the dashboard component.
So when I open this `localhost:9999/dashboard` I want react to redirect to `localhost:9999/dashboard/home` and also show the components  if the user is logged in.

I tried to do this :

```
return (
        <Route
            {...options}
            render={(props) =>
                store.get("userData") ?
                    <Redirect to="/dashboard/home" component={<Component {...props}} />
                    :
                    <Redirect to="/"/>
            }
        />
    );
```

This did route to the home page but nothing was visible at all. I mean the components inside dashboard weren't visible at all as well.

This is what I am getting. You see it redirects but doesn't show anything:

[image]

Comment: Move this to stackblitz or codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could be more specific about which file is the code that you are showing.

But I feel that what you are trying to accomplish something like this:

**PrivateRouter**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, restricted, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            user.auth == true ?
                <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
            :   <Redirect to="/dashboard/home" />

        )} />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: no, this isn't what i want. I'll give you a summary of what i wanna do: I have a login page and a dashboard page. login is public and dashboard is private. Inside the dashboard I have routed all the components: home, complaints etc. Now the problem is if i go to localhost:9999/dashboard it should redirect to .dashboard/home so that i can see the components of Home. but since it isnt redirecting it's not showing the home component

Comment: so as you can see my private component, if I redirect it to /dashboard/home , it redirects but does not show the components inside home idk why. although it should. I think im not redirectin it correctly or I. not using the private component correctly